# Liferay portlet with Angular, Pulling configurations from other portlets

Tags: json, angular, liferay

Is there a way to pull the configurations of other portlets or categories within a single angular portlet? I was hoping to use a single system configuration in multiple portlets. In the feature > configuration json, I have added this code that I was hoping would work but I can't get it back into the portlet.

```js
    "system": {
        "category": "related.configuration",
        "name": "Related Configurations",
        "fields": {
            "development": {
              "type": "boolean",
              "name": "Developer Mode",
              "description": "Should the portlets be set to developer mode?",
              "default": false
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with this configuration setup.  The configurations are for :

- Individual portlets
- All portlets of that type